# build ios app with visual studio using xamarin, without mac build host

Tags: macos, build, xamarin, host

I am a new user to xamarin. 
I installed Xamarin.IOS on visual studio. When i create a new project and want to build it, vs says that you should select a "mac build host".
Is it necessary for building ios application?
May I do that in a simulator? because I don't have a Mac machine.
Thank you very much.

Comment: From my understanding, you have to build the iOS version on a Mac.  I was listening to a podcast, and the guest used xamarin, and I remeber him specifically mentioning that.

Answer (score 3):

You must have a Mac to act either as a build host or your primary development machine in order to build an iOS app.  The iOS build process relies on the Apple iOS SDK and tools that are ONLY available from Apple on OS X.

Comment: May I use a simylator instead of using a mac?

Comment: A simulator of what?  If you mean a OS X VM, that is prohibited by Apple's license.  It may be technically possible.

Comment: I mean, a mac simulator on windows. can i connect to it from visual studio and use it as a build host?

Comment: Read my last comment.  This is prohibited by Apple's OS X license.

Comment: May I run Xamarin.IOS in another Apple devices suchas ipad, ipod or iphone?

Comment: No.  It requires a machine that can run XCode and developer tools.

Answer (score 3):

If you are completely refused any idea of buying Mac here the solution. In my case I use next tools:

- Windows 8.1 x64
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (Xamarin inside)
- VMWare Workstation 12
- Inside VMWare Workstation:

  - OS X 10.11 El Capitan
  - XCode 7.1 (Xamarin's developers recommend 7.3)
  - Xamarin Community 6.0.1

General advice is to use latest versions and updates of all tools.

1. Install El Capitan as it described [here](http://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-on-vmware-on-pc/).
2. On VM install latest XCode (you probably need Apple ID for it) and iOS part of Xamarin Studio. If Xamarin Installer generates error on downloading JDK 7 then [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and install it before Xamarin Studio
3. Enable Remote Login in MacOS settings and allow access for your user
4. Configure VM network as NAT and make port forwarding for port 22
5. Run Visual Studio on Windows and create iOS project.
6. Connect to Mac using IP 127.0.0.1 and type your Mac's username and password
7. Select appropriate iOS emulator in Visual Studio and run.
8. Here the proof pic [image: proof pic]

Comment: Holey moses, I can't begin to _try_ to guess the amount of RAM still freely available in you machine.
Win 8.1 + VS2015 is painfully heavy... Add that to VM... Ugh

Comment: My RAM amount is 16 GB so nothing terrible happened :)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this topic I've tried many approaches. I spent too many hours trying to install hackintosh on a VM on my MS Windows 10 system... I tried a lot of receipts... I could install it free times but I couldn't reboot it none of the tries. @#£%&!!!!

Before this anoying "R&D" I searched for a cheap second hand Mac and I also searched after but without getting good results...

Today I want to share my next step with you all before starting with it because I guess (I hope indeed) is going to be the solution for my next 4-6 months to do iOS developments with xamarin using VS on a Windows machine without owning a Mac, use a Mac hosting already prepared for dev purposes:

https://www.macincloud.com/checkout/managed.html

Answer (score 1):

For setting up Xamarin iOS with Windows and Visual Studio, you'll need to have MAC to run / test the application in the simulator.

Please review the limitation here http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/

You can either install MAC OS X in your windows PC using VM Ware and setup MAC OS